# Hibernate - more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a scenario to extract information from three(Table1, Table2, Table4) tables based on the common id of Table1

For extracting information from Table 4, I have to look another intermediate table(Table3) for the common Id between Table 3 and Table 4. The query result of Table 4 information would contain more than a single row as query response.

I have written the following HQL(Hibernate Query) for my requirement

```
select t1,t2,(select t4.column1 from Table4 t4 
join Table3 t3 on t4.column0=t3.column0 and t3.column1=t1 and t3.column2='desired_value') from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t2.column1=t1.column1 
where t1.column0=:id and t1.column3=:value
```

I have entity classes for all the four tables.

How can I select the multiple rows from the subquery

What is the euiquvalent of POSTGRESQL array_agg() / string_agg() method in Spring Data JPA?

Without the subquery, I am able to fetch Object[] response with my Entity class objects.

How can I add my subquery in order to retrieve all my desired data in a Single transaction without creating a separate query method in my Repository class?

What I tried so far:

```
select t1,t2,(select new List(t4.column1) from Table4 t4 
join Table3 t3 on t4.column0=t3.column0 and t3.column1=t1 and t3.column2='desired_value') from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t2.column1=t1.column1 
where t1.column0=:id and t1.column3=:value
```

Below is the output object that I am trying to achieve:

```
List<Object[]> as my query response 

         where each Object[] will be of size 3 with following

                 Object[0] -> Table1_Entity object
                 Object[1] -> Table2_Entity object
                 Object[2] -> will be a String[] containing a specific column values from Table4 Entity class
```

i.e response = [[obj1, obj2, ["value1, value2","value3"]], [obj3, obj4, ["value1, value2","value3"]], ......]

Comment: JPA/Hibernate has no support for `string_agg` or `array_agg`, as both of these functions are particular to Postgres, but not other databases.  If you want a workaround, then you might want to add sample data and also show us the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Kindly find my expected sample response data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1,t2, (select cast(function('string_agg', t4.column1, ', ') as string) from Table4 t4 
join Table3 t3 on t4.column0=t3.column0 and t3.column1=t1 and t3.column2='desired_value') from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t2.column1=t1.column1 
where t1.column0=:id and t1.column3=:value
```

Comment: I tried but getting following query syntax exception  Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (string_agg)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'string_agg' {originalText=string_agg}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Let me try the new edit and give an update

Comment: Meh, the cast must be around the select item in the subquery. Updated again.

Comment: Could you please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192574/hql-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value/67193045#67193045 and help me