# HQL - Check if an Array contains a value

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have an array field in my first entity Class as below:

```
class Entity1{
       private Integer col1;
       private String col2;
       private Integer[] col3Arr;
}
```

I have another entity class as below:

```
class Entity2{
       private Integer col1;
       private String col2;
       private Integer col3;
}
```

I am fetching records by joining multiple other entities along with which I have to join Entity1 if col3Arr contains a value col3 from Entity 2

With PSQL, I could easily achieve this by following statement

```
//Other part of query
join Entity2 e2 on (//conditions from other joined tables//)
join Entity1 e1 on e2.col3=ANY(e1.col3Arr)
```

What is the HQL equivalent of ANY?
Or is there any other way in HQL to check if an array contains a specific value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mapping the arrays you will need a custom type. You can use the hibernate-types project for this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Did you try to use `e2.col3 = FUNCTION('ANY', e1.col3Arr)` yet? If that doesn't work, I would suggest you create a custom `SQLFunction` that renders the SQL you desire e.g.

```
public class ArrayAny implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return firstArgumentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        return "any(" + args.get(0) + ")";
    }
}
```

You will have to register the function within the Dialect.

Comment: Thanks again!!!! e2.col3 = FUNCTION('ANY', e1.col3Arr) This works!!!

Comment: (e2.col3 = FUNCTION('ANY', e1.col3Arr) saved my day:) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-array):

> When discussing arrays, *it is important to understand the distinction between SQL array types and Java arrays that are mapped as part of the application’s domain model.*
>
> *Not all databases implement the SQL-99 ARRAY type and, for this reason, Hibernate doesn’t support native database array types.*

So, there is no equivalent of PSQL ANY in HQL.

Comment: Could you please tell how I can join the table based on array containing a specific value?

Comment: I see two options: 1) Use native sql here. 2) Try to  extend your hibernate dialect by registering a function that will responsible for comparison `e2.col3=ANY(e1.col3Arr)` and then use this function in HQL. And also you will need to write your own [hibernate custom type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) or use some library like [this one](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types)

Comment: I tried using native sql but I get org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003. How can I register the array type in PostgresqlDialect

Comment: See implementations of dialects that provided by hibernate. I guess you can find some examples there.