# How to construct criteriaQuery to match a specified String with List<String>

Tags: hibernate, criteriaquery

```
 public class MyEntity{
     private Long id;

     @Convert(converter = MyEntity.StringListConverter.class)
     private List<String> names= new ArrayList<>();          
 }
```

The field *names* in database is a string in jsonArray format, such as ["Washington","Mosco","London"].
I want to check whether a name called "alex" is in the field *names*. How to build criteriaQuery？

```
     CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
       CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> criteriaQuery = 
       criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
       Root<MyEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyEntity.class);
       criteriaQuery.select(root);
       Predicate restrictions = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();

       if(null != inName){/*inName is such as "alex" */
        restrictions = criteriaBuilder.and(restrictions ,...);

       }
```

how to construct the second argument of "criteriaBuilder.and"?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check whether the value of some column of `MyEntity` is contained into `names` list?

Comment: I want to check  whether a value as query condition is contained in name list. 
for example , a record of MyEntity whose names with the values ["abc","def"] will satisfy the query to find the records containing "abc" in name field.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom function for this. See this answer for [HQL - Check if an Array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192574/hql-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value/67196916#67196916) which should work the same way for you.